# UITextView in inputAccessoryView will not resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, first-responder

I have a view of a `UIViewController` which has a `UITextField` as a subview. The text field implements an event on `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin`. This event sets the `inputAccessoryView` of the text field and adds a "shadow" view on the view of the view controller to block interaction with the view.

The `inputAccesoryView` is a `UIView` with a `UITextView` as subview. The `UITextView` is set as `firstResponder` when the keyboard shows (registered on `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`).

When the "shadow" view is touched I call the following method:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    self.dimScreenView.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.writingView.txtView.text = @"";

    [self.writingView.txtView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But the keyboard does not disappear when the shadow view is touched. I have tried calling the `[self.writingView.txtWritingField endEditing:YES]` and `[self.writingView endEditing:YES]`, but I cannot make it work.

Should I do something special to make the keyboard disappear when the `inputAccessoryView` has a subview, that is `firstResponder`?

**Update:**

It turns out, that the `UITextView` and `UITextField` both returns `NO` on the `isFirstResponder` property, even if I do not call `resignFirstResponder`. How can none of the text views be `firstResponder` while the keyboard is still present?

Comment: are you sure dismissKeyboard is triggered?

Comment: Yes, I have had break points in it and the shadow view also disappears when touched.

Comment: writingView and txtView are not nil?

Comment: Nope. They are both valid pointers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

like @malex said, after `[self.writingView.txtView resignFirstResponder];`, your `UITextField` becomes the first responder again. So you should add the code let the `UITextField` resign first responder too:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    self.dimScreenView.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.writingView.txtView.text = @"";

    [self.writingView.txtView resignFirstResponder];
    [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention `UITextView` is set as `firstResponder` but in the code you are passing `resignFirstResponder` to the textField instance. Try calling `resignFirstResponder` on the textview instance.

Comment: Sorry, it might seem unclear in the code. The `txtWritingField` is the `UITextView`. I will edit the name to `txtView` to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

After 
    [self.writingView.txtView resignFirstResponder];

your textField becomes the first responder again and keyboard is on screen with former inputAccessoryView staying from textView. So you only need to reload it:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    self.dimScreenView.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.writingView.txtView.text = @"";

    [self.writingView.txtView resignFirstResponder];

    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = nil;
    [self.textField reloadInputViews];
}
```

In this way you can hide inputAccessoryView but you need another way to make it the first responder again because focus moves to textField immediately.

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but I can't make the accessoryView disappear, which made me investigate the `firstResponder`. It turns out, that the `UITextView` and `UITextField` both returns `NO` on the `isFirstResponder` property, even if I do not call `resignFirstResponder`. That seems very strange to me. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: In my model case UITextField has viewable focus after [UITextView resignFirstResponder]. It is strange if both of your fields don't have.
So in my case self.textField isFirstResponder and I reload input view.